# Cakephp3, How to use where clause and inner join in cakephp3?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to get review tables from product table.
and I added column name 'delete_yn' which means the review is deleted or not.
I used some cake query below

```
return $this->Product->find()
        ->contain(['ProductReview', 'Users'])
        ->where(['Product.product_code' => $productCode])
        ->toArray();
```

and the result is this fine.

However, now I want to check if the review was deleted by a user and show only 'n' in the column 'del_yn'
I added this query

```
->andWhere(['Product.ProductReview.del_yn' => 'n'])
```

after where clause.

But it does not work.

Please Help.

Comment: Try:- `return $this->Product->find()
        ->contain(['ProductReview', 'Users'])
        ->where(['Product.product_code' => $productCode,'ChProduct.ChProductReview.del_yn' => 'n'])
        ->toArray();`

Comment: Why do the aliases suddenly change from `Product` and `ProductReview` to `ChProduct` and `ChProductReview`?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I wanted to ease you guys to read easily. I will updated it. Thanks you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `andWhere(['Product.ProductReview.del_yn' => 'n'])` , use `matching` (if cakephp 3.0.x) or `innerJoinWith()` if(cakephp 3.1.x) and filter records matching specific associated data. For example,

```
return $this->Product->find()
            ->matching('ProductReview', function ($q) {
               return $q->where(['ProductReview.del_yn' => 'n']);
            })
            ->contain(['ProductReview', 'Users'])
            ->where(['Product.product_code' => $productCode])
            ->group('Product.id')
            ->toArray();
```

Comment: @SterlingArcher answer edited to explain why this works.

Comment: Yes I tried this code and I got what i wanted However, I got it double which means same results in a object and I got two of the object. I don't know why

Comment: @EricLee  i think you have has many relationship between Products and ProductReviews , you can group results by  Products.id , answer edited

Comment: Yes. they have has many relationship. thank you now i get it right